# How to show currency symbol (¥) in numeric?

Tags: handsontable

I was able to get default `USD $`,using

```
cellProperties.type = "numeric";  
cellProperties.format = "$0,0.00";
```

How to show `CNY ¥` in numeric?

I tried,

```
cellProperties.type = "numeric";  
cellProperties.format = "¥0,0.00"
```

It shows only number with thousand comma, no any currency symbol, no error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Handsontable uses the [Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com) library to handle its number formatting. As it's written in [the docs](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.24.3/demo-numeric.html), the currency symbol (as well as other display options) depend on the "locale" of the cell, configurable via the `language:` option. To get it running for CHN, include the corresponding translation file and then set the language to 'chn':

```
<script src="https://docs.handsontable.com/0.24.3/bower_components/numeraljs/languages/chs.js"></script>
```

Here's a sample [JSFiddle snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/a75vat68/) to demonstrate your use-case.